# Fill blank rows in a column with a non-blank value above it in Spark

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, databricks

I have an input file having around 8.5+ Million records.
My requirement is to fill the empty row values in a column with the immediate non-blank value **ABOVE** it. Have a look at the example:

[image: Have a look at the example:]

---

```
+-----+-----+---+------+
|FName|LName|Age|Gender|
+-----+-----+---+------+
|    A|    B| 29|     M|
|    A|    C| 12|      |
|    B|    D| 35|      |
|    Q|    D| 85|     F|
|    W|    R| 14|      |
+-----+-----+---+------+


Desired Ouput:

+-----+-----+---+------+
|FName|LName|Age|Gender|
+-----+-----+---+------+
|    A|    B| 29|     M|
|    A|    C| 12|     M|
|    B|    D| 35|     M|
|    Q|    D| 85|     F|
|    W|    R| 14|     F|
+-----+-----+---+------+
```

Comment: unable see image, could you post content here.

Comment: Added the same in the post.
FYI: Link to image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRXjV.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Increment column can be added, and function "last" with ignoring nulls can be used over window:

```
val idWindow = Window.orderBy($"ID")
df
  .withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
  .withColumn("Gender",
    last(
      when($"Gender" === "", null).otherwise($"Gender"),
      ignoreNulls = true).over(idWindow)
  )
  .drop("id")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add rowId column with a Gender_temp and mark even odd column as M and F 
save it to Gender_temp
and drop the unused columns

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object DataframeFill {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess
    import spark.implicits._

    val personDF = Seq(("A", "B", 29, "M"),
      ("A", "C", 12, ""),
      ("B", "D", 35, "F"),
      ("Q", "D", 85, ""),
      ("W", "R", 14, "")).toDF("FName", "LName", "Age", "Gender")

    personDF.show()

    personDF
    .withColumn("rowId", monotonically_increasing_id())
      .withColumn("Gender_temp", when($"Gender".isin(""),
      when ($"rowId" % 2 ===0 ,"M").otherwise("F") ).otherwise($"Gender"))
      .drop("Gender")
      .drop("rowId")
      .withColumnRenamed("Gender_temp","Gender")
          .show()


  }

}
```